# Call in an empty two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, call

Trying to set up the calls for procedures, but keep getting error C2660: function does not take [x] arguments. Prototypes are fine and give no error, and neither do the headers of each procedure, just the calls. What am I doing wrong?

```
int     sc[3][4], low[3];
double  avg[3];

getScores(sc, 3);
findLowest(sc, 3, low);
calcAverage(sc, 3, low);
display(sc, 3, low, avg);
```

The function prototypes are

```
void getScores(int[][4]);
void findLowest(int[][4], int[]);
void calcAverage(int[][4], int[]);
void display(int[][4], int[], double[]);
```

Comment: which line is failing?

Comment: all of the calls, 

getScores(sc, 3);
findLowest(sc, 3, low);
calcAverage(sc, 3, low);
display(sc, 3, low, avg);

Comment: What does the getScores function look like?  Can you post code for it?

Comment: What are your function prototypes?

Comment: void getScores(int[][4]);
void findLowest(int[][4], int[]);
void calcAverage(int[][4], int[]);
void display(int[][4], int[], double[]);

Comment: getScores only takes 1 paramter according to your prototype

Comment: Actually none of function calls match your prototypes

Comment: My professor said since they're all arrays, you should use void for all of them, is that not right?

Comment: Well now your prototype for `calcAverage` shows that it is supposed to take 4 arguments, but you only pass 3.

Comment: @RachOliveros There are definitely cases where you would want a non-`void` function that takes arrays. Depends on what you are trying to achieve with the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the arguments that you are passing into your functions do not match the number of arguments that your function is supposed to take.  You keep passing in one more argument than the function takes.

For example, your getScores function only takes one argument, a two dimensional array, but you try to pass in two (a 2D array and an integer).

Comment: The dumb thing is, I did it correctly on a one-dimensional array, and completely forgot to do so for this one! Thank you so much, definitely won't forget that again!